# Flask / Jinja dict object has no element 0

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

We are using Flask to show info about playing cards when a user visits a specific url. Taking the serial numbers from the url like so:

example.com/dinos/123x124x145 where X delimits the serial numbers.

```
@app.route('/dino/<string:num>')
def dinopage(num):
    test=num.split("x")
    print (test)
    assets = "application/static/assets/dinos.json"
    with open(assets) as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        size=len(test)
        for i in range(size):
         print(i)
         dinodata = data["cardino"+test[i]]
         print(dinodata)
         
         print(len(dinodata))
        return render_template('dinogrid.html', noofdinos=len(test), data=dinodata)
```

For a single serial everything works. We use a template to pull out items and display them from the json.

```
{{ data["species"] }}
```

However when I try to loop the template using

```
{%for i in range(0, noofdinos)%}
{{data[i]["species"] }}
{%endfor%}
```

I'm greeted with

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: dict object has no element 0
```

a console print out shows that i am picking up the correct data. But obviously i am not showing it to Jinja in the correct way. For example this is the console output produced by visiting /dino/6851x12

```
['6851', '12']
0
{'name': 'Cardino #6851', 'image': 'QmY8xmQRKHXckUWSzwmGd6AyxxnNk6RadW79QCjbSGtcAm', 'src': 'QmRFVS7Y48vaBL91EuBk8pVaXzu4wWngCh3UeALGE2Qj3Q', 'type': 'image/png', 'species': 'Parasaurolophus (5.16%)', 'dinoRarity': 'Rare', 'attributes': {'badge': 'Cardino Purple (6.60%)', 'background': 'Mars (5.27%)', 'colour': 'Dino Green (7.03%)', 'itemcount': '4 (27.21%)', 'items': [{'lefthand': 'Mystical Lantern (4.36%)', 'rarity': 'Uncommon'}, {'righthand': '', 'rarity': ''}, {'tail': 'Flame (4.55%)', 'rarity': 'Uncommon'}, {'eye': '', 'rarity': ''}, {'shoes': 'Wellies (10.09%)', 'rarity': 'Common'}, {'tummy': 'Dino Skull (3.75%)', 'rarity': 'Rare'}]}, 'publisher': 'https://cardinos.io', 'artist': ['MAAD Frog Ro Marenghi', 'http://maadfrog.com'], 'creators': ['przcntn', 'LegionOfBrad'], 'release': 'S1'}
11
1
{'name': 'Cardino #12', 'image': 'QmQRMyLHprSDswZt6T15htkjgxbPrWRzfGsfyjtc2Pm6TQ', 'src': 'QmVD7g8ZhdpnsQX7qLPmaRLKyacWuoBdTLhqRskWRwzrBD', 'type': 'image/png', 'species': 'Corythosaurus (11.61%)', 'dinoRarity': 'Common', 'attributes': {'badge': 'Cardino Turquoise (7.11%)', 'background': 'Yellow (16.68%)', 'colour': 'Violet (5.25%)', 'itemcount': '5 (12.14%)', 'items': [{'lefthand': 'Futuristic Cane (4.42%)', 'rarity': 'Uncommon'}, {'righthand': 'Bone (4.27%)', 'rarity': 'Uncommon'}, {'tail': '', 'rarity': ''}, {'eye': 'Terminator Eye (8.41%)', 'rarity': 'Common'}, {'shoes': 'Wellies (10.09%)', 'rarity': 'Common'}, {'tummy': 
'Football (4.93%)', 'rarity': 'Common'}]}, 'publisher': 'https://cardinos.io', 'artist': ['MAAD Frog Ro Marenghi', 'http://maadfrog.com'], 'creators': ['przcntn', 'LegionOfBrad'], 'release': 'S1'}
11
```

My question is how to i present this to the loop in Jinja correctly?

Comment: Does `data["species"][i]` instead of `data[i]["species"]` work?

Comment: That appears to take the cycle through the letters in #12's species. So the first output on the loop is C, and then next time it is O.

Comment: What is the structure and datatype of `data`? The error message suggests that `data` is a dict. If this is indeed the case, then the iteration fails because you are trying to access entries in `data` as if it was a list.

Answer (score 0):

`dinodata` in your flask app needs to be a list that you append new dinos to. Right now it is just a variable that gets overwritten with every iteration of the loop.

```
@app.route('/dino/<string:num>')
def dinopage(num):
    test=num.split("x")
    print (test)
    assets = "application/static/assets/dinos.json"
    dinodata = []
    with open(assets) as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        size=len(test)
        for i in range(size):
            print(i)
            dinodata.append(data["cardino"+test[i]])
            print(dinodata)
         
            print(len(dinodata))
    return render_template('dinogrid.html', noofdinos=len(test), data=dinodata)
```